# Why it does not return the right date?

Tags: php

If somebdoy may help me?, I have a problem with method mktime.
Here is my code:

```
$now = new DateTime("now");
echo $now->format('Y-m-d')."\n";

$nowYear=intval($now->format('Y'));
var_dump($nowYear)."\n";

$nowMonth=intval($now->format('m'));
var_dump($nowMonth)."\n";

$nowDay=intval($now->format('d'));
var_dump($nowDay)."\n";

$end=date('Y-m-d',mktime(0,0,0,'2021','03','01'));
echo $end."\n";
```

The value returned by `$end` is wrong. It returns **2169-05-03** instead of **2021-03-01**.

Comment: Your parameters are in the wrong order. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php shows the `mktime` parameters should be hour, minute, second, month, day, year.

Answer (score 2):

### [mktime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

```
mktime ( int $hour , int|null $minute = null , int|null $second = null , 
         int|null $month = null , int|null $day = null , int|null $year = null ) : int|false
```

Last 3 arguments should be `month`, `day` and `year`. You passed `'2021','03','01'`